# How to do caching in php

Tags: php, caching

I used the following code, but it is taking time. i want to cache without storing in a text file.

```
$file = 'cache_toppers.txt';
if (file_exists($file) &&
    filemtime($file) > (time() - $expire)) {
    $records = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
} else {
   include("kalvidbconnect.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM vpfmsttoppers";
    $result = mysql_query($query)
        or die (mysql_error());
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
        $records[] = $record;
    }
    $OUTPUT = serialize($records);
    $fp = fopen($file,"w");
    fputs($fp, $OUTPUT);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Thanks,
Kamatchi.D

Comment: Where would you like to store the information? I don't expect you'll find a faster form of storage than a local disk (for data that needs to persist across requests). More likely, it's not the storage that's a problem, but the `unserialize` process.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ready to use PHP extensions providing cache functionality. Some of them:

- memcache http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache
- APC http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php
- eAccelerator
- XCache

these are the ones I know of, but surely there are many more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, use cache then, for example **APC** - [`apc_store()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php)/ [`apc_fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php)

Comment: Your apc_store() ljnk has a trailing "." which is breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, not sure, but how about using CouchDB!?
Here is a good tutorial on IBM http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-couchdb/index.html?ca=drs-

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use file-based caching, then one option is to build a wrapper and store it in shared memory,

http://se.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php

Maybe APC utilizes the same technique, I don't know, but if you don't want to install PECL-extensions then building your own cache-handling might be an option.

I would however consider caching rendered content to file, since that would put the least amount of load on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on a very long list of factors, I'd typically expect trying to unserialize the file to take longer than loading it fresh from the database.